How to merge different sculpt mesh
So I sculpted hands for my 3d character and I would like to join it with the main character. However, when I join the hand mesh and character mesh with ctrl J, the border line between the meshes are visible. I have tried to use the dyntopo feature to hide the border line,  however it doesn't work.
Is there another way of hiding the  border line of mesh

Joining the two objects together doesn’t automatically bridge between their meshes, it just puts the meshes within the same data block and connects it to the active object, deleting the objects the other meshes came from. To connect tubular meshes like this, I might suggest you consider using Bridge Edge Loops, but since these are sculpted you’ll probably have to delete the ends of them first to put the bridge in.

Thanks for the answer
